# ADF Staged Copy Not Applying Schema Mapping for XML

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to copy data between a SOAP Web Service and an Azure SQL Database. When I use the staging option of the copy activity, mappings are not applied and no data is copied. If I disable the stage and write directly to a text file, mappings are applied as expected. **How can I make the mappings apply when the staging option is enabled?**

### Additional Information

**Source:** HTTP
**Sink:** Azure SQL Database

Direct copies between the source and sink do not work because of where they're located, so I need to stage the copy.

[image: Staged copy UI]

However, when staging the copy, the defined mappings are not being applied and the sink database table ends up with a single null row.

[image: Schema mapping]

[image: Data loaded to SQL table]

When using a delimited text sink without a staging step, the mappings work as expected.

[image: Unstaged copy]

However, as soon as I add a staging step, the same issue occurs with a delimited text sink.

[image: Staged copy]

**Question:**

Comment: When staging option is enabled, How was data stored in stg container

Comment: The data is stored as XML in the staging container

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the same issue. I used http (xml response) as source and Azure SQL DB as sink. Staging is also stored as XML file. While doing so, few columns are null and only few data are getting copied in sink. Mapping is not happening as given in mapping tab of copy activity.

[image]

This issue is not happening when another source format like delimited file is used. In those cases, Mapping occurs as given in the mapping tab.

Perhaps you can try the workaround of using two copy activities. One copy activity from HTTP source to blob and then blob to sink. And these activities should happen sequentially.

- In copy data activity 1, HTTP is used as source and csv file in Blob storage is used as a sink.

[image: List item]

- In Mapping tab, I have given the corresponding mapping
  [image]
- In copy activity 2, I used same dataset for blob storage as a source dataset and Azure SQL db sink dataset.
- In copy activity 2 also, I tested with auto-mapping and with manual mapping. Both worked in my case.

**Final Sink Table**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @Aswin, and for taking the time to try and reproduce this. That was going to be my fallback / workaround if there's no other way around this. I was just hoping to avoid it because it needlessly complicates the pipeline with two additional activities - copy to delimted text staging file and delete staging file.